# How can you run a query in BigQuery to match logs where the callerIP is not within a certain list of IP ranges?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run the following query in BigQuery - I am confident that the rest of the query is correct however the only issue is how I have listed the IP addresses in the line below. I am being presented with the error message "Encountered " <FLOATING_LITERAL> "x.y "" at line 17, column 62" ( where x and y are integers)

```html
      AND NOT (protopayload_auditlog.requestMetadata.callerIp : "IP-RANGE IP-RANGE IP-RANGE IP-RANGE")
```

Where IP-RANGE is of course of the form x.y.z.f-x.y.z.e

I am not sure how to format this string of IP addresses to make the query work. Would be really grateful for some assistance!

The below, is the full query;

```html
#legacySQL
SELECT
  protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail AS principalEmail,
  resource.labels.project_id AS project_id,
  resource.labels.bucket_name AS bucket_name,
  resource.labels.method AS method,
  protopayload_auditlog.requestMetadata.callerIp AS callerIp,
  timestamp AS timestamp
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([projectid.organisation_audit_logging.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_],
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -40, 'DAY'),
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -38, 'DAY')))
WHERE
  protopayload_auditlog.serviceName = "storage.googleapis.com"
  AND resource.labels.method = 'google.storage.objects.get'
  AND REGEXP_MATCH(protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail, r"^.*@mycompany\.com")
  AND NOT (protopayload_auditlog.requestMetadata.callerIp : "IP-RANGE IP-RANGE IP-RANGE IP-RANGE")
LIMIT 500
```

Comment: can you share few sample data.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "sample data"?

Comment: some data that you run this query on.

Answer (score 0):

you can employ below approach as a starting point - you can wrap up all lengthy stuff into into UDF to make it compact and readable

```
AND NOT net.ipv4_to_int64(net.safe_ip_from_string(protopayload_auditlog.requestMetadata.callerIp)) between net.ipv4_to_int64(net.safe_ip_from_string(ip_range1_start)) and net.ipv4_to_int64(net.safe_ip_from_string(ip_range1_end))
AND NOT net.ipv4_to_int64(net.safe_ip_from_string(protopayload_auditlog.requestMetadata.callerIp)) between net.ipv4_to_int64(net.safe_ip_from_string(ip_range2_start)) and net.ipv4_to_int64(net.safe_ip_from_string(ip_range2_end))
...
```